# Azure function local debugging Error after .net core 3.1 upgrade

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

We recently upgraded azure functions project to .NET Core 3.1 & able to build and publish changes to Function app, problem is when we try to debug code locally when it hits below line of code getting error as below

```
var eInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventInfo>(requestBody);
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think the error is something to do with that line. To verify it, put a breakpoint to any line prior to the line you shared.

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable source server support, clean your solution and then rebuild. Please have a try of this.

Comment: Thank you for reply, this error happens when .net core 3.1 is upgraded with below configuration in csproj file <PropertyGroup> <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion> </PropertyGroup> – if its updated as<PropertyGroup> <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion> </PropertyGroup> issue is resolved